# Can i store a ruby hash in a mysql database column

Tags: mysql, ruby, hash

I want to insert hashes like below into a mysql column,

```
{:sub => ["at","div.product-info"],
     1 => [["at","span#hs18Price"]],
     :avail => ["at","strong.out_stock"],
     :soffer =>  ["at","div.freebie"], 
     :stime =>["search","div[@class='costs']//span[@class='days']"],
     :scost => [300,30] }
```

I tried, its throwing the following error,

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'costs...
```

Any help?

**EDIT:**

Forget active record and serialization. I want to do it in a raw sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to escape the single quotes in your hash

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store Hash inside column in MySQL (or any other database supported by AR*) you have to:

1) define column as text

```
add_column :users, :the_whatever, :text
```

2) define serialization of column so that ActiveRecord knows what to do with you data. You do this by setting serialize option to model.

```
serialize :the_whatever, Hash
```

* Some databases (like PostgreSQL) also provide some other types more suited for storing Hashes. See [Railscasts Hstore](http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore).

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to switch the database: PostreSQL has [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html) for this.

Comment: Postgres 9.2 has a JSON data type as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql column must be of type `text`. You might need to serialize your hash first too.